# keyboardWillShow fire twice

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-events

I'm stuck with problem "keyboardWillShow" fires twice, but the "keyboardWillHide" called once.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/x-hovo-x/KeyboardWillShow.git) where I'm printing the keyboard sizes as soon as "keyboardWillShow" fires.
I've also put breakpoint in "viewDidLoad" and the observer registers only once.
I've added two elements "UITextField" and "UITextView" and for both it is the same behaviour.

I'm using iOS 9.2, swift lang., xcode 7

Below my ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        print("keyboardWillShow sizes: \(keyboardSize)")
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("HideHideHide")
}

}
```

**UPDATE**

First time it fires once with sizes: 
keyboardWillShow sizes: (0.0, 568.0, 320.0, **253.0**)

for the rest it twice with different sizes:(second y position is changed also the height changed)
keyboardWillShow sizes: (0.0, 568.0, 320.0, **216.0**)
keyboardWillShow sizes: (0.0, **352.0**, 320.0, **216.0**)

Comment: I remember i got this before, its kinda a bug with Xcode or iOS 9 sth, so i add a BOOL then set it to YES on `keyboardWillShow` then execute the code along with it

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using anything but the default keyboard here, but in cases when 3rd party keyboards are being used, the system will call it once with the height  of the system keyboard, and then again with the height of the actual keyboard you're using once the extension loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is connected to simulator 
On the real device it fires once as supposed to be.

Comment: Actually for me on iphone7(real device) keyboardWillShow is getting called twice. On simulator it is called once. But it is 3 years since the answer. Just noting it here so somebody might find it useful.

Comment: If you provide a code example I'll try and let you know what happens on my real device.

Comment: I found out that mine was related to having secure textfield. Setting isSecureEntry on uitextfield calls the keyboardWillShow notification.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you subscribe to more than one `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and forgot to unsubscribe from them.

Try to add observer in `viewWillAppear` and remove it in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: Search for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification in you're project and remove it and see if it helps

Comment: I don't have any other code than provided here. 
If you check [an example](https://github.com/x-hovo-x/KeyboardWillShow.git) you will see that this is simple view application with one view with code provided here.

Answer (score 1):

Are setting the Text Input Traits - Keyboard Type?

**Example:** If you set the Keyboard Type as "Number Pad", ideally it should call once, but it gets called twice. Please check that and be sure.

**Resolution:** You can maintain a bool to check if the keyboard is already up or not, and check its value while executing the selector code block.

Comment: do you mean you tried it and this is a case? Otherwise, there is already an explanation (the correct answer), the issue was connected to the simulator. Why I'm writing 'was' cause I didn't check it for a while.
And for me, just curious, why you decided to write an answer cause you came across the same problem or?

Comment: Yes I came across the same issue and nothing helped. Finally realised what I have posted, to help people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only entering this `ViewController` or are you navigating through several `ViewControllers`? Right now I can't see any code to unsubscribe from the notifications which means than once you enter this `ViewController` again it will subscribe again (providing its `viewDidLoad` method runs again). Weird that only one of them fires twice though. Good practice is to subscribe and unsubscribe in the respective opposite methods. If you subscribe in ViewDidLoad then unsubscribe in deinit. If you subscribe in `viewWillAppear`, unsubscribe in `viewWillDisappear` etc.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Check so that deinit runs when leaving the `ViewController`.

Comment: I have only one ViewController and this is initial one, no any navigation.
Generally you are right but I didn't want to add "unnecessary" part into my [example](https://github.com/x-hovo-x/KeyboardWillShow.git).
Also I already wrote I put breakpoint into the viewDidLoad and the registration took place only once.

Comment: Ah, missed that sorry. The only difference between your code and the code I use is that I set my Selector differently. Don't know if it will make a difference, but can't hurt to try:

   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "hideKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

Comment: Tried it out same result.
but what is the interesting is that y position is different 
keyboardWillShow sizes: (0.0, 568.0, 320.0, 216.0)
keyboardWillShow sizes: (0.0, 352.0, 320.0, 216.0)

Comment: Sounds like the second firing comes after viewDidLayoutSubviews. Have no idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

I remove all added keyboards and leave only the system's , then the method will fire only one time.If add a new keyboard ,the method still fire two times. Maybe it's a system bug. [System Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgOPk.png)